# Use computed columns in related table in power query on SQLITE via odbc

Tags: join, powerquery

In power query ( version included with exel 2016, PC ), is it possible to refer to a computed column of a related table?

Say I have an sqlite database as follow

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE products (
        iddb INTEGER NOT NULL,
        px FLOAT,
        PRIMARY KEY (iddb)
);
INSERT INTO "products" VALUES(0,0.0);
INSERT INTO "products" VALUES(1,1.1);
INSERT INTO "products" VALUES(2,2.2);
INSERT INTO "products" VALUES(3,3.3);
INSERT INTO "products" VALUES(4,4.4);
CREATE TABLE sales (
        iddb INTEGER NOT NULL,
        quantity INTEGER,
        product_iddb INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (iddb),
        FOREIGN KEY(product_iddb) REFERENCES products (iddb)
);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(0,0,0);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(2,2,2);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(3,3,3);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(4,4,4);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(5,5,0);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(6,6,1);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(7,7,2);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(8,8,3);
INSERT INTO "sales" VALUES(9,9,4);
COMMIT;
```

basically we have products ( iddb, px ) and sales of those products ( iddb, quantity, product_iddb )

I load this data in power query by:

A. creating an ODBC data source using SQLITE3 driver : **testDSN**

B. in excel : data / new query , feeding this connection string Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;DSN=**testDSN**;

Now in power query I add a computed column, say `px10 = px * 10` to the product table.
In the sales table, I can expand the `product` table into `product.px`, but not `product.px10` . Shouldn't it be doable? ( in this simplified example I could expand first product.px and then create the px10 column in the sales table, but then any new table needinng px10 from product would require me to repeat the work... )

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a Merge step from the sales query to connect it to the product query (which will include your calculated column).  Then I would expand the Table returned to get your px10 column.

This is instead of expanding the Value column representing the product SQL table, which gets generated using the SQL foreign key.

You will have to come back and add any further columns added to the product query to the expansion list, but at least the column definition is only in one place.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming you don't modify existing values, only create new values. When you add the new column to `product` it creates a new table, and doesn't modify the `product` table that shows up in related tables. Adding a new column over `product` can't show up in Odbc's tables unless you apply that transformation to all related tables.

What you could do is generalize the "add a computed column" into a function that takes a table or record and adds the extra field. Then just apply that over each table in your database.

Here's an example against Northwind in SQL Server

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(".", "Northwind_Copy"),
    AddAColumn = (data) => if data is table then Table.AddColumn(data, "UnitPrice10x", each [UnitPrice] * 10) 
        else if data is record then Record.AddField(data, "UnitPrice10x", data[UnitPrice] * 10) 
        else data,
    TransformedSource = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Data", (data) => if data is table then Table.TransformColumns(data, {"Products", AddAColumn}, null, MissingField.Ignore) else data}),
    OrderDetails = TransformedSource{[Schema="dbo",Item="Order Details"]}[Data],
    #"Expanded Products" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(OrderDetails, "Products", {"UnitPrice", "UnitPrice10x"}, {"Products.UnitPrice", "Products.UnitPrice10x"})
in
    #"Expanded Products"
```

Comment: Thanks for the piecing together the code and adding the table / record subtlety. Having to copy functions for each table feels clumsy though; in the 2010 version of power pivot, you'd just use RELATED() and be able to access extra columns, it was more intuitive.